# Dynamically sized RecyclerView items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm attempting to create a RecyclerView which displays a TV Guide. Something like this:

```
         [12:00PM] [12:30PM] [1:00PM] [1:30PM ] [2:00PM] [2:30PM]
[Chan 1] [-show1-] [------show2-----] [----------show3----------]
[Chan 2] [------show1------] [-----show2------] [-----show3-----]
```

The provided LayoutManagers don't seem to support this type of layout. I've started to write my own LayoutManager, but I've hit a roadblock.

When the LayoutManager adds a view for an item, it only knows the item's position in the dataset. It doesn't have access to the item itself.

This is a problem since the width of each "show" is dependant on the start/end time of the show. Therefore, it seems the LayoutManager would need to be able to see the values of the "show" itself in order to layout the view for it correctly.

How can this type of layout be achieved with RecyclerView?

Comment: see for example `GridLayoutManager` and `GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup` sources

Comment: That doesn't quite fit my needs. It would work for the example I gave, but in reality the "span size" is a float since there's no guarantee that each show will be a multiple of 30 minutes. Some shows are <5 mins, others are >3 hours.

Comment: On second thought, the concept of looking up the size of an item might be what I need for my custom LayoutManager. I'll try it out.

Comment: so that's why I said how they did it with int span - you should do similar thing but with float span - btw cannot you use that GLM where one span is 5 minutes so if one show is 45 minutes long you would return 9?

Comment: That would work, although I'm skeptical of the performance. I need a granularity of 1 minute, and may display a week or more of data. This means I could end up with over 10k "spans" -- would that hurt performance?

Comment: I have no bloody idea ;-( try it and post results here - I am also courius

Comment: @pskink Sorry for the late reply -- this project sort of got put on the backburner. I tried using GridLayoutManager, but it doesn't quite fit my needs. The `SpanSizeLookup` suggestion does solve my original question though. If you'd like to write up an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. Cheers.